# Scheduling Autorep command to run daily

Tags: scheduling, autosys

I am a newbie to autosys. I am trying to get the jobs execution information on daily basis into a csv file. For this I am trying to write an autosys job which I can schedule to run daily. Below is the snippet of the code:

```
insert_job: job_run_time   job_type: CMD 

box_name: box_job_run_time

command: autorep -J box_job1 -r -1
```

But this is giving the below error:

> 'autorep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Please help with the solution

Comment: Direct the result into some file. Like below

autorep -J box_job1 -r -1 >> Output.csv

Answer (score 0):

Shanky, before you run autorep command directly on the terminal, it's required to configure first to read Autosys DB storing the run details.
Mostly it would be a few variables and instance names.

Please check with the scheduling team on how to configure Autosys client on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Piyush and Mansi for your reply!

Mansi, where this command autorep -J box_job1 -r -1 >> Output.csv can be configured? so that it can be scheduled to run daily.

Comment: Either directly placing in the command attribute or as through custom script.